# Working scrolling anchors

Tags: jquery

Hi guys ive been trying to get smooth scrolling working on my anchors for ages but can never get it right.

Ive tried ifxscrollto plugin and it just flat out won't work for me and a few others.... anyone got suggestions?

PS: I want a script that automatically grabs named anchors.

Comment: Or something like this http://djpate.com/portfolio/jSlideto/example/index.html http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hard to understand what your asking for.  Something like this maybe?

http://beski.wordpress.com/2009/04/21/scroll-effect-with-local-anchors-jquery/

Comment: Thanks... modified that script so it automatically effects local anchors without applying class `$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a[href^="#"]').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
 var full_url = this.href;
  var parts = full_url.split("#");
  var trgt = parts[1];
  var target_offset = $("#"+trgt).offset();
  var target_top = target_offset.top;
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:target_top}, 500);
 });
});`

Answer (score 0):

Not exact code, but would something like this work, if I understand your question correctly:

```
$("#mn a").click(function(){
      var aTarget = $(this).attr("href");
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(aTarget).offset().top}, 800);
      return false;
   });
```

It's what I use in my site to scroll smoothly from an `a` that has a `div`'s ID as its(the `a`'s) `href` value.